# Server Error on Angular 15 application deployed to Azure app service

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying to get my angular application deployed to azure app service but am encountering a server error that I cannot seem to resolve:

**server error:**

[image]

I have tried setting the default document to index.html:

**default document:**
[image]

and creating a web.config file and adding the path to angular.json:

**web.config:**
[image]

**angular.json:**

[image]

to no avail I am still encountering the same issue. the app was deployed successfully and running just can't seem to get resolve the runtime error.

Comment: Please try to avoid images and try to give source code for easier tests.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been trying to get my angular application deployed to azure app service but am encountering a server error

- Check logs for the error details and to know what causing the issue:
- Check if all the files of your application is deployed properly to App Service
  Go to *App Service->Development Tools->Advanced Tools->Debug Console->cmd->Site->wwwroot*

[image]

Try adding below code Snippet in `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Instead of `<action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />`

And also check the path in Path mappings->Virtual applications and directories:

[image]

- Also, You can check changing the Physical Path to `Site/wwwroot/<your_app_name>`